# How to deal with "translate this for me"

Tags: support, questions, flags

I've come across a number of questions ([this one being the most recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748336/from-asp-net-c-sharp-to-php)) which is asking for someone to translate some code from language A in to language B, often without showing any effort on their part.

Given that this question is unlikely to be useful to anyone in the future, what is the correct way of flagging such a question?

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. **Questions without a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers."_ I'd say that kindof applies.

Comment: @Cerbrus I guess the "why isn't this code working" part threw me off since the code itself wasn't broken. That last line seems to clear things up though. Thanks.

Comment: *Too Broad* should  also works as there are many ways to translate the code.

Comment: And it's closed. Delete-vote cast.

Comment: I'm mostly using _too broad_ as close reason for such cases.

Comment: I normally use a custom close reason (*I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code conversion service*). However, last time I did that a moderator removed the auto-generated comment (maybe acting upon a flag). So it may be frowned upon, although I'm at a loss to explain why.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi  If you close-vote with no comment or reason, you get meta posts describing you as a 'nazi mod' for leaving no clue.  If you leave a reason, you get meta posts describing you as 'hostile and unhelpful'.  You have to choose which way you want to be hated:(