# I waited nearly one hour, but my post has only five views

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How to convert labels shape from (x,1) to (x, )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326499/how-to-convert-labels-shape-from-x-1-to-x)

I waited nearly one hour, but my post has only five views. I created this account, because my main account was banned already five months ago. Are my views in my new account connected with my old account?

Comment: No, the old account has nothing to do with whether or not your question is interesting enough to attract views. Though I’m sure this one will certainly attract a certain kind of attention to both the question and the account

Comment: I mean this account's days are numbered, but the problem with the question is that the tags don't look like they're relevant to the actual question.  Are you using Python?  What libraries are you using with it again?  What is a simple sample set that you can show us here that replicates your problem?

Comment: Not leaving out punctuation inbetween sentences in a paragraph would be a ***great*** start. Readers don't want to suffer through such incomprehensible text; they leave and look for a better question.

Comment: i mean... punctuation surely has nothing to do with whether or not someone views a question. whether they stick around tho,

Comment: "My main account was banned already five months ago." - It sounds like your original account is question banned, but that allows you to ask a single question, once every 6 months.  Using a second account to bypass your question ban isn't a good thing. Waiting an hour, for an answer, is not enough time.

Comment: @Makoto looks more like its seconds were numbered. Anyway, the question is a boring duplicate once properly retagged.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel:  0 is still a number :D

Answer (score 10):

#### Because there are a lot of questions, some don't get looked at much

When I got to this, after you asked this and caused a bunch of people from meta to view the question, it *still* had only 35 views.

We get over 4200 questions on an average day (as determined by looking at the last 30 days).  We don't have enough people looking at questions in order for all questions to get a substantial number of views. For some totally made-up numbers, if the average person answering questions opens 20 questions a day, we'd need over 2100 people viewing questions every day for each of them to get even 10 views in a day.

There are things to do to increase visibility, such as making sure your question is tagged correctly.  This question was originally tagged [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning) [neural-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neural-network) [computer-vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision) [conv-neural-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conv-neural-network), for a question in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) that appears to be about using [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) arrays in [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow).  Had any of those tags been present, you would have been more likely to reach someone who would find the question relevant and click on it.  Having a good, descriptive title is also important (this was done correctly here).

Comment: So, you're saying I need to keep creating new accounts and reposting my questions frequently in order to ensure that they'll be seen?

Comment: @CodyGray While you're at it, you could vote for the other accounts' questions, too.  And preferably post on meta about it.

Comment: Only 4200? That sounds low. End of the school period I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question, ignoring issues specific to the person asking:

### Tag your question according to the question you have

... **not** according to the overall problem you are trying to solve.

It **does not matter** that the reason you want to reshape the data is as part of some computer vision, deep learning program etc. etc. What matters is that you have a Numpy array (created as part of using those deep-learning libraries) and are writing Python code, and want to reshape the array.

As a rule of thumb, *almost every* question on Stack Overflow should be tagged with *exactly one* tag that is the **name of a programming language**. Questions where no language can be tagged, are theoretical questions - we take those, and even have some very useful ones, but they're often better on the [Computer Science Stack Exchange site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) etc. Questions about taking working code from one language to another ("translating" it) are **not questions about** the first language, and should [normally be rephrased](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300553).

### Ask at a more active time of day/week

This also has some effect. Stack Overflow is a North American centric site, and many experts are in the middle of their work day.

Comment: Not sure I'd call [~19%](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#key-territories-country) an overwhelming majority

Comment: @Phil considering its the highest, and the second highest is about half of that at ~9%, its not unreasonable

Comment: @Shorn that's not really how it works. There are more Stack Overflow contributors outside the US (and similar timezones) than there are within it. To say this is a North American centric site is simply incorrect

Comment: @Shorn It makes no sense comparing individual countries, if you want approximate timezones. There is almost double of users from Europe than North America.